# bst insert segfault when checking if root is NULL

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am trying to insert values to bst but when I check if root is NULL before inserting, I get a segfault. How do I initialize the tree to NULL first or what am I doing wrong?

```
void StdClass::add(int val, ...){
    Node *temp, *parent;

    if (root == NULL) {//throws segfault here..
        root = new Node(...);
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        temp = root;
        return;
    } else {
        temp=root;
        while (temp!=NULL) {
            if (val <= temp->key){
                parent = temp;
                temp=temp->left;
                //root =temp;
                return;
            } else {
                parent =temp;
                temp=temp->right;
                //root=temp;
                return;
            }
        }
        Node *newNode = new Node(...);
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right = NULL;

    //Now insert the new node BELOW parent
    if(val <= parent->key){
        parent->left = newNode;}
    else{
        parent->right = newNode;
    }
}
```

}

root is defined in private in StdClass..

```
struct Node{
    int key;
    std:string b;
    std::string c;

    Node *parent;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;

    Node(){};

    Node(int val, std::string s, std::string t){
        key = val;
        b= s;
        c = t;

    }
}
Class StdClass{
    public:
        void add(int, std::string, std::string);
    private:
        Node *root;
}
```

calling it from another function..

```
void StdClass::test(){
    int x = 0;
    while(x < 10){
        add(x,"test","test");
        x++;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "StdClass.h"
int main(){
    StdClass s;
    s.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only way to get a crash where you say you do (you have used a debugger to check it?) is if the `StdClass` *object* is not valid, i.e. you call `add` on a null or otherwise illegal pointer. When in the debugger, check what `this` points to, and if it's valid.

Comment: Also can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Including how you create the `StdClass` object and call your `test` function.

Comment: Lastly a little and unrelated note about your loop in the `test` function: That loop is the same as `for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) add(x, "test", "test");` While the end-result is the same, a `for` loop might be a better alternative.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg if I don't check if root is null and try to create new Node..it does work. yeah used a debugger to check it is that spot..I

Comment: Your example is not complete. You forgot the definition of `StdClass`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg updated. Okay will switch.

Comment: As for making your example minimal, you should be able to remove the entire else branch if it's never entered and the program crashes on the conditional test.

Comment: There are a few things missing, like what does the `Node` constructor do? You *do* set the `Node::key` member variable somewhere? At what point in the loop in `test` does the crash happens, the first time `add` is called? The second time? Is it different?

Comment: Oh, and you *do* have a `StdClass` constructor that initializes `root`? Not initializing `root` will lead to *undefined behavior* as it will most likely not be a null pointer (its value will be *indeterminate*). UB is a major reason for crashes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am not initializing root anywhere.

Comment: @mashertmos your example does not compile. It has several errors. There is no keyword `Class` in c++. The definition of `StdClass` does not declare `test` even though it's called. The definition of neither class ends in semicolon. Surely you must have forgotten to test your own example code. Test your code before posting.

Comment: Then you *definitely* have to initialize `root`.

Comment: @user2079303 I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with my class definition and initialization because it's working fine, yeah there is a typo with the keyword.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  would that be `root = new Node(0,"","");root->left= NULL;root->right= NULL;` in the constructor ?

Comment: No, just `root = NULL` (or `root(NULL)` in member initializer list).

Comment: okay, let me check it now.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thank you. it works now.